# Why is my title for the question not good enough?

Tags: support, title

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57989765/196241) on Stack Overflow and wanted to title it as 'Why "try" does not cause error?', but Stack Overflow automagic says:

> Title cannot contain "Why "try" does not cause error?".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question.
>   For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

I think, my proposed title summarizes my question pretty well. Why is it not acceptable?

Comment: The word "error" is banned, it has caused too many pr0blems.  You can use "diagnostic".

Comment: @Hans, "diagnostic" is not applicable for that question. And the word is not banned, it mostly just requires a longer title.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for explanation. Still, it seems pretty silly to blacklist word "error" in the World of Errors. AFAIU now, my other title was accepted, because it was longer

Comment: [758,102 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aerror) support what @yivi wrote

Comment: "AFAIU now, my other title was accepted, because it was longer" - it also contains more useful detail, so it seems like the blacklisting worked.

Comment: Re *'Why "try" does not cause error?'*: Se [question formation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=2m46s).